# Recreate visreg() data ticks in border using ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, visreg

I would like to recreate the data ticks found in the border of `visreg()` logistic regression plots using `ggplot()`. 
[image]

I can get the data points plotted with `geom_point()`, but these are in the axis space, and I would like to get them in the border.
[image]

I've tried looking at the source code with `getAnywhere()` for the `visreg()` function but I can't see anything informative there. Any ideas? 
A reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(visreg)

y <- rep(c("0","1"), each = 50)
x <- c(rnorm(50,70,20),rnorm(50,30,20))
y <- as.numeric(y)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
glm1 <- glm(y~x, data = df, family = binomial)

visreg(glm1, type="conditional", scale = "response")

df$fit <- predict(glm1)
df$fit.response <- exp(df$fit)/(1+exp(df$fit))

# For simple ribbon
df$lower <- df$fit - predict(glm1, se.fit = TRUE)$se.fit
df$upper <- df$fit + predict(glm1, se.fit = TRUE)$se.fit
df$low.response <- exp(df$lower)/(1+exp(df$lower))
df$upp.response <- exp(df$upper)/(1+exp(df$upper))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = fit.response))+
geom_ribbon(aes(x=x, ymin = low.response, ymax = upp.response), alpha = 0.3)+
geom_line(colour = "blue")+
geom_point(data = df, aes(x=x, y=y))+
theme_bw()

getAnywhere(visreg)
```

Comment: Do you need `+ scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))` ? Or perhaps `+ coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE, clip = "off")`

Comment: Have you considered replacing your `geom_point()` with `geom_rug()`?

Comment: ah excellent I think `geom_rug()` is what I was looking for but didn't know it existed.